# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller support for rate limiting specific api paths

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

Nginx supports rate limit over specific api calls.
I want to do the same using Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller. However, when I apply annotation provided: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps, it  is putting rate limit over all api paths. Is it possible to do rate limit specific api paths in Kubenetes Nginx Ingress controller and what is the way to do it?

Comment: You can put your deployment .yaml file onto different namespace.

Comment: I got the solution, its working and its: create different ingress for different rate limit over different apis.

Comment: @user2067572. can you share more about how you resolve?